# git - Calculate the mean number of characters per commit message per author

Tags: bash, git, commit

I'd like to calculate the mean number of characters per commit message per author in a git repo - I'm not very good with bash unfortunately so I really have no idea how to start!

Comment: I appreciate that I have made no attempt, but I really just don't know how. I have done some googling and finding other statistics are quite easy (i.e. number of commits per author):

https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/3fb7ef0c0cbdb72412fc

However this I imagine will involve `sed`/`wc` maybe `grep`? I really just don't know :)

Comment: Start with something like `git log --pretty="%an:%s"`, then split that to get author and message. Now store the length of message (and total number of messages) for each author, then calculate the  average for each at the end. Good luck!